# Intentando obtener datos de una pagina usando Ajax Jquery

Tags: ajax, access-control-allow-origen

Me planteo  realizar una consulta a una pagina usando Ajax de esta manera

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    baseUrl = "http://botxtrem.000webhostapp.com/red/unico.php";
    $.ajax({
        url: baseUrl,
        type: "get",
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
}
});
});
```

El problema es que no captura ningún dato solo da un error :

[image: Error al intentar obtener respuesta]

**Failed to load http://botxtrem.000webhostapp.com/red/unico.php: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.**

Existe una solución de dicho problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso es una medida de seguridad denominada CORS, es asunto del lado del servidor, en tu PHP prueba agregando la función al principio del archivo:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: claro ese era el problema gracias